# Why do we need to use a sigmoid function when using backpropagation?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, backpropagation

Why can't we just use a step function then when calculating the weights use,

```
weightChange = n * (t-o) * i

Where, n: learning rate;
t: target out;
o: actual out;
i: input
```

This works with single layer networks. I've heard a sigmoid is needed to deal with non linear problems but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, you don't *need* a sigmoid activation function. What you need is a differentiable function that serves as an approximation to the step function. As an alternative to the sigmoid, you could instead use a [hyperbolic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function) tangent function.

For multi-layer perceptron networks, the simple perceptron learning rule does not provide a means for determining how a weight several layers from the output should be adjusted, based on a given output error. The backpropagation learning rule relies on the fact that the sigmoid function is differentiable, which makes it possible to characterize the rate of change in the output layer error with respect to a change in a particular weight (even if the weight is multiple layers away from the output). Note that as the `k` parameter of the sigmoid tends toward infinity, the sigmoid approaches the step function, which is the activation function used in the basic perceptron.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something here but how come the perceptron learning rule uses the input when calculating the weight update, but back prop needs a sigmoid derivative of the output? Why would the input work for the learning rule but not back prop?

When you say it characterizes the rate of change in the output layer, how exactly would it do that using just an output from the current node?

Comment: With the simple perceptron, the input only has one path to the output so the input times the error tells you if the weight has to increase or decrease. With the MLP, there are multiple paths from each input to each output neuron so the simple perceptron update rule doesn't work. If the sigmoid output of a neuron is `y`, then the derivative is just `y(1 - y)`. The *backpropagation* is because you update weights of the output layer using its output error, the sigmoid derivative, and it's inputs (from the previous layer), then repeat for each previous layer back to the input layer.

Answer (score 5):

`Sigmoid` activation allows for a smooth curve of real values numbers from [0,1]. This way, the errors can be calculated and tuned in such a way that the next time you perfmorm feed-forward, it  will output not just integers, but predictions from [0,1]. This way you can choose which to ignore, and which to accept.

What you described would be a binary neuron, which is completely acceptable as well. But the sigmoid activated neurons give you that spectrum of [0,1]

Comment: I understand what it does but why exactly can't you apply a step function and the perception learning algorithm to multi-layer networks?

Comment: I'm sure that it exists -- but they're different types of neural nets